# java out of memory exception while encoding and decoding image in to base64

Tags: java, image, out-of-memory

i am trying to upload images and retrieving with help of `Base64 encoding & decoding`

as follows

**decoding**

```
if (imgString != null ) {  
    BufferedImage image = null;
    byte[] imageByte;

    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imgString);
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
    image = ImageIO.read(bis);
    bis.close();

    String realPath  = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/images/"+studentDetails.getFirstname()+".png");

    File outputfile = new File(realPath);    
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile); 
        studentDetails.setStuImg(outputfile.toString());
    }
```

While decoding I am getting sometimes the following Exception

> May 27, 2018 3:04:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>       SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/campasAdmin] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space] with root cause
>       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

**encoding**

```
if (imagePath != null && imagePath.length() > 0) {      
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(imagePath));
    encodedFile = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
}
```

What is the solution to it? How would I avoid it?

Comment: More memory is used by decoding the image to pixels than by base64 decoding. However, even that should not be a problem unless the images are really huge and the available memory is tiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the solution to it? How would I avoid it?

Two possible approaches:

### Increase the heap size.

Unless your images are huge, you should be able to hold an image in pixel and base64 format in memory ... a few times over.

### Stream the image.

Your code for reading and writing the image is loading the entire image into memory and then writing it out.  You don't need to do that.  Instead, you can process it in clunks:

1. read a chuck from the source,
2. encode or decode the Base64 data,
3. write the encoded / decoded chunk to the destination
4. repeat ... until the stream has been consumed.

The linked Q&A provides some illustrations of how to do this.

Comment: thank you @Stephen C Can you please provide  a example for streaming the image

Comment: Read the linked Q&A

Comment: getting this Error   `The method encodeBase64(byte[]) is undefined for the type Base64`